# Should binom.test to be used to test that the coins are fair in R? If not, what test should I use?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, self-study, binomial-distribution

[image]

Image above shows the question, I'm wondering whether I'm solving the question correctly.

```
binom.test(x = 4, n = 100, p = 0.5, conf.level = 0.98)
```

```
    Exact binomial test

data:  4 and 100
number of successes = 4, number of trials = 100, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
98 percent confidence interval:
 0.008323647 0.111704427
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                  0.04
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - you need to test whether the observed data follow a binomial distribution using a **Chi-square test**.

For example, the probability of getting no heads from 4 tosses of a coin (or tossing four coins) if the coins are fair is:

```
dbinom(0, 4, 0.5)
# [1] 0.0625
```

Do this for the other possibilities (1, 2, 3, and 4 heads).

Now use the chi-square test to test your hypothesis and supply the probabilities:

```
    chisq.test(c(5,23,39,19,14), p=dbinom(0:4, 4, 0.5))
    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  obs
X-squared = 11.52, df = 4, p-value = 0.0213
```

So the coins are fair, but only just at the 2% level of significance. However, the number of times 4 heads appears (14) is more than expected (6.25).

Comment: So p-value = 0.0213 greater than α = 0.02, it should be failed to reject H0?

Comment: yes. at the 2% level of significance, as stated in the question. But change one result from head to tail and the p-value jumps to 0.07!

Answer (score 3):

The answers by @JTH and @Edward propose different solutions, a binomial test of the null $p=0.5$ or a chi-squared test of the null of a binomial distribution with $p=0.5$. These hypothesis are not equal, the later implies the former. But $p=0.5$ could equally be satisfied with four coins with unequal probabilities but $\bar{p}=0.5$. That could for example be a betabinomial distribution. So if it is important to reject if the $p$'s are unequal bet "fair on average", the chi-square test would be best, but if it enough to test the null of "fair on average", I would expect the binomial test to have higher power, since it does not spend power on some of the alternatives that the chi-square test must consider.

So let us do some simulations to see if that is correct. We use R and for the tests, the functions `chisq.test` and `binom.test`.  First, let us look at the quality of the chisquared approximate distribution under the null hypothesis: (All simulations based on 50000 replications)

[image: histograms of chi-squared under the null]

Shown is histograms on the natural and log scale, with the theoretical density superposed. The approximation seems good, except maybe in the extreme right tail.

Then we look at histograms of the p-values, for both tests. Ideally, under the null they should be uniform, but here we have some discreteness:

[image: p-value histograms under the null]

For the binomial test (`binom.test`) the discreetness is quite pronounced.  Then we look at p-value distributions under an alternative quite close to the null, $p=0.55$. For alternatives much farther from the null, the power is essentially 1.

[image: p-value distributions under an alternative]

It looks like for the binomial test, the p-value distribution tends to be stochastically smaller than for the chi-square test, indicating that it tends to reject more often, so has higher power. Indeed, for the traditional $0.05$ level we get powers of

```
chi-square test  binomial test 
   0.32156        0.47896
```

confirming that.

Finally, let us see at a qqplot of the two p-value distributions to see more rigorously if we have stochastic domination:

[image: qqplot of the two p-value distributions]

We see that, except at the very upper end, the p-values from the binomial test are systematically smaller than the p-values from the chi-square test,confirming that the former will have higher power at all reasonable levels.

Comment: This is a very good analysis, Kjetil. How do we account for the fact that your simulation shows greater power from the binomial test, but in this specific question, we find a smaller p-value from the chi-squared test?

Comment: @JTH - Probably because we aren't testing the same. If the coins are fair on average because two of them have opposite biases, the sample will have an average p close to 0.5 (50% heads) and therefore a large p-value for the binom.test, but the distribution will be somehow different from the binomial (more 2 head tosses and less 0 head and 4 head tosses), so p-value for the chisq.test will be small. Even with fair coins, a random sample can produce the same effect some times.

Answer (score 1):

I have a different way of looking at the problem. I think you can use `binom.test` here, but you have not invoked the command correctly. You should use `x = 214` (the number of heads observed in the experiment) and `n = 400` (four coins tossed 100 times)

I get

```
> binom.test(214, 400)$p.value
[1] 0.1769419
```

So, no reason to reject.

Comment: Why the downvote? That seems like a correct, if short, answer ... fairness means $p=0.5$, and it is not necessary with a chisq.test for that

Comment: Thanks, I think my answer and the chi-sq answer test the same null. Perhaps the chi-sq answer is more powerful.

Comment: Could you have a look at my new answer to this Q?